# GitLab pages monetization

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages

I Hope some of you can answer some of these questions

- Am I allowed to monetize my GitLab Pages website?
- Am I allowed to add ads to my GitLab pages website?
- Am I allowed to set up pay-per-click?

What are the limitations?

I havent found any information in GitLab Terms of Use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted GitLab, and the person called [Lanice Sims](https://drift.me/lanice) answered me.

She answered `Yes to all of the above.`